# Laravel Nova Tool - Adding pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-nova

So the problem is that `Resources` has pagination out of the box, but when you use `Tool` as custom Resource, then you don't have pagination. Do I have to use another `npm package` and do it manually, or use existing one that is used in Resources?

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually implement the backend logic yourself but laravel does provide some vue mixins to help with the vue side:

```
import { Paginatable, PerPageable } from 'laravel-nova'
```

In the mixins section:

```
mixins: [
    Paginatable,
    PerPageable,
]
```

In your template you can add:

```
<pagination-links
    v-if="resourceResponse"
    :resource-name="resourceName"
    :resources="resources"
    :resource-response="resourceResponse"
    @previous="selectPreviousPage"
    @next="selectNextPage">
</pagination-links>
```

Check out `vendor/laravel/nova/resources/js/views/Index.vue` for a full example of how they do it for each resources page.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: import from 'laravel-nova' no longer works in Nova 4 whats the new method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the Laravel 5.7 pagination?

You can find more information at the following links: 
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-pagination-link-customizations and https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Comment: Yeah, but I need Vuejs pagination :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Nova Resources are displayed using the "simple" style. However, you may customize this to use the "links" style. You can enable this by setting the pagination option in your config/nova.php configuration file:

```
'pagination' => 'links',
```

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/#pagination